# Video tag for IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, video

I have an issue connected with playing video at IOS, I have a video tag created with React, like this.

```
<div className="video-component-wrapper" >
      <video
        id="video"
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop
        src="someSrc.mp4"
        // type="video/mp4"
        playsInline
        preload="metadata"
      >
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <div
        className="sound-control-wrapper"
        onClick={() => toggleMuted()}
      >
        <div>{isMuted ? "unmute" : "mute"}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am getting such a view on IOS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tewn2.jpg)

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem. So you made a video tag in ReactJS and...??? Does a `<video>` tag work with same file?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that video on IOS is not playing it just shows a white screen